# Error when deploying a Symfony2 app with capifony

Tags: symfony, capifony

I'm trying to deploy but I'm getting an error when doing this command:

```
php app/console assets:install web --env=prod
```

The error is:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
You have requested a non-existent parameter "secret".
```

and capifony is rolling back so nothing is deployed... But this parameter exists in parameters.yml. I have an Amazon Linux with nginx.

Can anybody help me please?

EDIT
different error now

```
Warming up the cache for the prod environment with debug false
Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
Cannot load resource ".".
```

and still not working... I don't know how to proceed, no help? :(

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Capifony are you using? Had the same issue. Reinstalling capifony, backing up my Capfile in my project and running `capifony .` again fixed the issue. Checking the new cap file against the old one showed some big differences.

Answer (score 0):

Is parameters.yml included in the configuration file which is used in the production environment?

Comment: I'm using this command in deploy.rb
    set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
and it's imported in config.yml in every environment

Answer (score 0):

Check `.gitignore` file, by default it ignores `parameters.ini`, thus the "secret" param.